# Load js function when clicking on a yt-video?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, embed, yt

is it possible to execute a Java Script function once the Yt video has been started with a click?

My code looks like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>onclick event demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>onclick event demo</h3>
    <p>Fires when the element is clicked.</p>
    
        <embed
        onclick="VideoStart()"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qK9v-VFfdY0?start=478" style="border:1px solid;" 
        >
        
        
</body>
</html>


<script>
function VideoStart(){
    ***code executed when clicking on the Yt-Video***
}

</script>
```

But for some reason nothing happens when I start or stop the YT video with a mouse click. Could someone please help me with this. I would appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        //event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
          myFunction();
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
      function myFunction(){
        alert("Hello world");
      }
    </script>
  </body
```

> 

This should work. Just change the values for the one's you need. The `myFunction` will be called when the video starts playing.